# why it does not work? I am beginner of python

Tags: python, nlp

```
def cbow(phrase1,phrase2):

    vec1=cbow(phrase1)
    vec2=cbow(phrase2)
    print(vec)
    return np.dot(vec1,vec2)/(np.linalg.norm(vec1)*np.linalg.norm(vec2))

cbow("green apple","green apple")
```

TypeError: cbow() missing 1 required positional argument: 'phrase2'

Comment: Because there is a second argument `phrase2` that you are not supplying when calling the function

Comment: The recursive calls inside the function only pass one argument each. But that's going to recurse until it hits the system limit, so it's not clear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: `cbow` is probably an already defined function that creates a continuous bag-of-words embedding of a phrase. OP then attempts to make an own function of the same name, and in it call the other function.

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally redefine the (external) function `cbow`, then try to call the outer `cbow` function within your `cbow` function. Instead, your own `cbow` is called, which takes two parameters.

Solution: Rename your function, it has a misleading name anyways:

```
def my_function(phrase1,phrase2):

    vec1=cbow(phrase1)
    vec2=cbow(phrase2)
    print(vec1, vec2)
    return np.dot(vec1,vec2)/(np.linalg.norm(vec1)*np.linalg.norm(vec2))

my_function("green apple","green apple")
```